# What can cause the following error unable to initialize libusb: -99

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, libusb, intel-edison

I recently started work on an Intel Edison board with mini breakout kit which comes with Yocto as default. I flashed the board to install a Debian derived system called [Ubilinux](http://www.emutexlabs.com/ubilinux). After this the board was upgraded and updated. Then I tried to connect a few usb devices to check if either of the boards two usb ports recognize anything. The board would not respond.

Running

```
lsusb
unable to initialize libusb: -99
```

I understand that the above message occurs when USB drivers are not configured. I have tried running `lsusb` using the default Yocto distro that intel has on its [website](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-23242) and still the same message. From reading forums on Intels website I understand that this should not happen. Also tried to query the forums but Intel wants me to verify my email address via a link which I still haven't recieved after 4 hours. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or haven't understood the board properly.

```
dmesg | grep -i usb
[    0.204550] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.204649] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.204855] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.763857] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
[    0.763940] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
[    0.764071] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    0.766539] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.766865] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    0.766882] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    0.767000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.767180] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    0.767263] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[    0.767333] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[    1.575749] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.575769] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.635600] pmic_ccsm pmic_ccsm: USB VBUS Detected. Notifying OTG driver
[    4.985394] usb0: MAC 02:00:86:f2:d5:6b
[    4.985416] usb0: HOST MAC e2:4e:68:c6:da:cf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it depends on which platform you're using.

For the **Arduino Breakout Kit**, which I'm using, I just had to set the SW1 appropriately (push it towards the USB connector), after which lsusb works just fine and shows the connected device.

In your case for the **Mini Breakout Kit** I believe you may need to supply 12V through the J21 connector.  Some more details can be had at https://communities.intel.com/message/253226.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying the USB needs to be put in host, rather than device mode.  For the board without a switch, a cable/adapter which grounds the ID pin is probably needed (though hacking the kernel ?might? override that.)